How to show progress in collection view cell?
I using this code to create UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. Also I want to download file when user click on collection view cell. I use code in didSelectItemAt to start downloading. But also I want to show progress in cell when file is downloading. I trying to use cellForItemAt method to update progress view but this method not called. What method I need to use to update progress view every second?
class StoreViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>?
    let sections = Bundle.main.decode([Section].self, from: "section.json")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createCollectionView()
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
    
    func createDataSource() {
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, item in
            switch self.sections[indexPath.section].identifier {
            case "carouselCell": return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            default: return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func configure<T: SelfConfiguringCell>(_ cellType: T.Type, with item: Item, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: cellType.reuseIdentifier,
            for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue \(cellType)")
        }
        cell.configure(with: item)
        return cell
    }
    
    func reloadData() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        for section in sections { snapshot.appendItems(section.item, toSection: section) }
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
    func createCollectionView() {
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: SectionHeader.reuseIdentifier)
        
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        createDataSource()
        reloadData()
    }
    
    func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let section = self.sections[sectionIndex]
            switch section.identifier {
                
            case "сarouselCell": return self.carouselSection(using: section)
                
            default: return self.carouselSection(using: section)
            }
        }
        
        return layout
    }
    
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
            (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            
            let interGroupSpacing = CGFloat(32)
            let width = layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.width * 1.05
            let groupWidth = width / 3
            
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(groupWidth), heightDimension: .absolute(groupWidth))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            let centerOffset = (layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.height / 2) - (groupWidth / 2)
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: centerOffset, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
            section.interGroupSpacing = interGroupSpacing * 2.0
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
            section.contentInsetsReference = .none
            
            section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (items, offset, environment) in
                
                ///` Настройка масштаба ячеек:
                items.forEach { item in
                    let distanceFromCenter = abs((item.frame.midX - offset.x) - environment.container.contentSize.width / 2.0)
                    let minScale: CGFloat = 0.7
                    let maxScale: CGFloat = 1.1
                    let scale = max(maxScale - (distanceFromCenter / environment.container.contentSize.width), minScale)
                    item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
                }
            }
            
            return section
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CarouselCell {
            
            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
            let directory: String = path[0]
            let fileManager = FileManager()
            let destination = URL(fileURLWithPath: directory.appendingFormat("/\(indexPath.row+1)/\(indexPath.row+1).mp3"))
            
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destination.path){
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SampleViewVC(), animated: true)
            }else{
                
                downloadQueue[indexPath.row+1]?.append(indexPath.row+1)
                var queueArray = downloadQueue[indexPath.row+1] ?? [Int]()
                queueArray.append(indexPath.row+1)
                downloadQueue[indexPath.row+1] = queueArray
                    
                let url = URL(string: "\(indexPath.row+1).mp3")!
                let downloadManager = DownloadManager()
                downloadManager.identifier = indexPath.row+1
                downloadManager.tableId = indexPath.row+1
                downloadManager.folderPath = "\(indexPath.row+1)"
                let downloadTaskLocal = downloadManager.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
                downloadTaskLocal.resume()
                
                downloadManager.onProgress = { (row, tableId, progress) in
                    print("downloadManager.onProgress:\(row), \(tableId), \(String(format: "%.f%%", progress * 100))")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if progress <= 1.0 {
                            cell.progressView.progress = progress
                            if progress == 1.0 {
                            } else {
                                cell.title.text = "\(String(format: "%.f%%", progress * 100))"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

